# MongoDB Atlas Device sync can't select serverless cluster

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, realm, serverless, real-mode

Please help me.
I have created a Serverless instance in MongoDB Atlas. now under device sync, I need to connect the cluster but when I try to select the cluster to sync it was disabled, could not select it.

For your reference, I have attached the screenshots below-
[image]

I tried with a free cluster which is not serverless (i think) it works fine. But after creating serverless cluster it only shows the free cluster. then I deleted all and created a new serverless cluster only no free cluster but it is not allowing me to select the serverless cluster.

Comment: That seems odd. SO is a coding specific forum and there is little we can do to assist with third party server configurations. This is a SUPER question for the MongoDB team though. Look at your screenshot; in the lower right corner there's a chat help - use that to get assistance with this issue. For future reference, SO is for coding questions; write some code and when you get stuck, post it and your troubleshooting and we'll take a look. Server configuration questions are off topic. Please see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for the comment Jay. Chat is off till Monday. I got another question, could you suggest me how to upload media from mobile devices to a cloud. I mean should i use blob or what!

Comment: Depends on which `a cloud` you want to use. MongoDB has cloud storage as well as Firebase and a number of others as well. It will vary depending on which service you choose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Atlas Device Sync doesn't support serverless yet. You can find the up-to-date list of limitations on [this page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/serverless-instance-limitations/). As indicated on the page, it's not a limitation that will be lifted "soon", so for now your best bet is to use a classic instance.

Comment: Yup, you are right. Is there any way that all documents don't get flooded in every device after sync? I mean if a user submits a form that should not get synced to every device but "Mongo DB Atlas" only.

Comment: You can take a look at asymmetric sync - it's a unidirectional sync strategy that uploads data from the device to the server: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/sync/configure/sync-settings/#asymmetric-sync. Alternatively, you can use flexible sync and define the client queries in a way where only you don't pull in other users' data (e.g. `realm.all<Form>().filter("userId == $0", currentUserId)`).